# How can I use List(Of <T>) as MethodParameters in ObjectDataProvider? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have an Object 'ArticleMasterData' and a list with instances of this Object. To show it in the XamDataGrid I have to convert it to a DataTable, which i do with 'ListToDataTable'. First off the VB Code for it:

```
Private Function ListToDataTable(Of T)(ByVal AccessDataList As IList(Of T)) As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Dim fields() As FieldInfo = GetType(T).GetFields

    For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
        table.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.FieldType)
    Next
    For Each item As T In AccessDataList
        Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow
        For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
            row(field.Name) = field.GetValue(item)
        Next
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return table
End Function
```

I need now the list(Of ArticleMasterData) as MethodParamter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpImport"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type local:ArticleMasterData}"
                        MethodName="ListToDataTable"
                        >
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

How can I do this? I didn't find anything in the Documentation or on google, so I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to change it to a datatable to bind it to a datagrid.  You can bind it to a ListCollectionView(IList) instead and save the hassle.  This also gives you sorting and filtering capabilities.

Comment: @KevinCook You're right, this is way better. Thank you so much!